# type check for a field in table (postgres) rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a table Student(class_id(integer),marks(integer),rank(integer))

In my Seeds.rb file i have written something like this to make entry to table

Student.create(class_id:2 ,marks:"abcdef", rank: 2)

when i add these data to table by rake db:seed  command ,i was expecting i would not be allowed to add this ,because for marks field of student, string is being inserted instead of integer.But rails added this record without any problem.

so how do i ensure this kind of entry doesnot happen and my table ensures type check.Me a newbie to rails and postgres

Comment: Ok, add a validation inside the `Student` model to check the same. Then you will get the error.

Comment: @arupRakshit    okay this is at the model level,but cant i do something at the db level ,so postgres donot provide something for it at db level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a validation like below will work. Add it to the `Student` model.

```
validates :marks, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

Whenever you will try to create a `Student` record, this validation will be called by Rails. If it passes then the recored will be created, otherwise not. There are methods to check if a record is valid or not in rails.

Read the guide to know how [validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) works in rails.

Comment: @Rumour May be. But Doing it in ActiveRecord will have benefits when you are in Rails.

Comment: i was expecting a error or exception , but the above statement simply doesnot add the row which contains a field who's value is wrong.

Comment: @Rumour have you done a little study on Rails. Seems not. So please go through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html . Try `Student.create!(class_id:2 ,marks:"abcdef", rank: 2)` and see what goes on.